# Pixi.js npm installation import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js' V7

Tags: javascript, import, pixi.js

I've followed every step of the PIXI.js documentation but I cannot get it to work. In the basic useage example (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pixi.js?activeTab=readme), they are installing pixi.js with npm:
`npm install pixi.js`.
After that they are importing PIXI from 'pixi.js': `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'`. If I try to run my application after I've followed all the steps listed above, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "pixi.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Here is my code:

(I am using  JavaScript not TypeScript!)

In index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <title>TBDv2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.scss">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="js/Application.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

in Application.js:

```js
//  -> workaround but doesn't work with sprite loader
// import * as PIXI from '/node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.mjs';

import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
// import { Application, Loader, Sprite } from 'pixi.js';

const config = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
}

const app = new PIXI.Application(config);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

window.onresize = () => {
    app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

const Graphics = PIXI.Graphics;

const graphics = new Graphics();

graphics
    .lineStyle(2, 0x000, 1)
    .beginFill(0x123456)
    .drawPolygon([
        0, 0,
        50, 0,
        50, 50,
    ])
;

app.stage.addChild(graphics);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you already read this? https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v7-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 1):

### I believe this sort of "Bare Module" import requires the use of a bundler.

Bare Module imports are when you specify a name for the module, like 'pixi.js', rather than the path to the file, like './pixi.js'. Node does support this, but only on a server, for most Browsers do not support this functionality.

These days, it's often assumed that if you're using npm, you're probably also using a bundler, like Vite or Webpack. These tools allow you to use the Bare Module imports, because they're already mapping your dependencies to your files that import them so that they can bundle everything together all nicely.

For example, if you start a project by running `npm create vite@latest` and follow the prompts for Vanilla JS setup, you could then essentially replace the contents of the generated index.html with your existing index.html, and replace the contents of main.js with your Application.js. Then, run `npm run dev` to start the dev server, and it should hopefully work!